# Gradient of quadratic vector function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, scalar-fields

I'm struggling with this very simple gradient question.

[image]

Where...

[image]

Now I've already been told the answer is Ax + b, but I can't work out how to get to the first term. Intuitively it looks like a quadratic equation, but when I go through the expansion of 1/2 xAx, for each element, then differentiate, I get left with:

[image]

Or in other words AIx + Ax

What am I missing?

Comment: I would expect a $2$ in front of every coefficient as the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$ and this is a quadradic form. I expect your error lays in taking the derivative.

Comment: Well, taking the first term which before differentiation is: x_1^2 A11 + x_1*x_2 A12... etc. Then when we partially differentiate this by x_1 we get the first line in the above snapshot, no?

Comment: Did you use that the matrix is symmetric? This simplifies some terms.

Comment: Excuse me, found my mistake... Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The top row of your derivative  is incorrect. For example, the coefficient of the $x_2$ term for example will be $(A_{12} + A_{21})$ not just $A_{12}$. This is because the expression $x^TAx$ contains $A_{12}x_1x_2 + A_{21}x_2x_1$. You considered the first term but neglected the second.